# Gulp spritesmith 'getting started' task is doing nothing

Tags: gulp, grunt-spritesmith, gulp-spritesmith

I just copy pasted the getting started task :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');

gulp.task('sprite', function () {
    console.log("inside sprite");
    var spriteData = gulp.src('/assets/images/*.jpg').pipe(spritesmith({
        imgName: 'sprite.png',
        cssName: 'sprite.css'
    }));

    return spriteData.pipe(gulp.dest('/assets/images/sprites'));
});
```

When I run this task I get the response :

```
[19:42:03] Using gulpfile D:\Phase Zero\AfterMarket\Application\gulpfile.js
[19:42:03] Starting 'sprite'...
inside sprite
[19:42:03] Finished 'sprite' after 18 ms
```

But if I go to '/assets/images/sprites' its empty !

How do I debug here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using absolute paths in `gulp.src()` and `gulp.dest()`.

1. If your images are located in `D:\Phase Zero\AfterMarket\Application\assets\images` then use relative paths  instead:

   `gulp.src('assets/images/*.jpg')`

   `gulp.dest('assets/images/sprites')`
2. If your images are actually located in `D:\assets\images`, try including the drive letter:

   `gulp.src('D:/assets/images/*.jpg')`

   `gulp.dest('D:/assets/images/*.jpg')`

   (Disclaimer: I have no idea if this works, never used Gulp on Windows.)

Comment: Thank you. It was an issue with the paths

Comment: It does work with drive letters in Windows, just the way you have them.